# Scheme "Not a function" error

Tags: scheme

I am learning Scheme and I keep getting this error: "Error: 20 is not a function" from the following code:

```
(define myFunction (lambda (x y)
(* x y)))
(define (higherOrder func x y)
(
    func x y))

(display ((higherOrder myFunction 4 5)))
```

I am trying to pass a function as one of the arguments. It goes through with the math since it says "20" in the error message and (5 * 4 = 20) but then it thinks it is a function. What is the problem? I cannot figure it out. I am running this code on https://repl.it/languages/Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You have one too many pairs of parens, the expression `(higherOrder myFunction 4 5)` evaluates to the integer 20, then the repl tries to evaluate `(20)`, which it can't because 20 isn't a function. When Scheme evaluates a list (where a list is anything in parens that isn't quoted) the first entry in the list is assumed to be a function.

Change the last line to

```
(display (higherOrder myFunction 4 5))
```

Comment: @Adam: easy mistake to make, just takes practice to get used to.

Comment: I couldn't find any extra parenthesis in this code however do you think you could take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786327/scheme-error-4-6-5-87-7-is-not-a-function

Comment: @Adam: the first element in the list needs to be a function. `+` is a function for instance, myFunction is a function, 4 is not a function.