# 0 is not a function in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, higher-order-functions

I am getting the error '0 is not a function when I try applying `sum-of-prefixes` function to a list of numbers:

```
(define sum-of-prefixes
  (lambda (lat)
    (cond
     ((null? lat) '())
     ((null? (cdr lat)) (car lat))
     (else
      (sum-of-prefixes-b 0 lat '())))))

(define sum-of-prefixes-b
  (lambda (sum lat result)
    (cond
     ((null? lat) result)
     (else
      (sum-of-prefixes-b (+ sum (car lat)) (cdr lat) (cons (sum result)))))))
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786029/scheme-not-a-function-error), which appears to be similar, but I can't see in my code where an expression might be reduced to (0).

You can try evaluating it here:
https://repl.it/repls/GlamorousProbableBlocks

> (sum-of-prefixes '(1 2 4)) Error: 0 is not a function
>   [sum-of-prefixes, sum-of-prefixes-b, (anon)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the last line of `sum-of-prefixes-b`. It should be:

```
(sum-of-prefixes-b (+ sum (car lat)) (cdr lat) (cons sum result))))))
```

instead of:

```
(sum-of-prefixes-b (+ sum (car lat)) (cdr lat) (cons (sum result)))))))
```

`(sum result)` is interpreted as applying `sum` to `result`, but `sum` is not a function, is a variable with value `0`.

And perhaps you should change `((null? lat) result)` in `((null? lat) (reverse result))` if you want the sums of the prefixes in the same order as the list, assuming I inferred correctly the meaning of the function. In this case  I think you should also change the second branch of the conditional of the first function.